# jQuery: How add class on click and (re)load for radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, checked

how can I customize the jQuery code so that
the added class is visible immediately and doesn't disappear on reload?

Is it necessary to somehow add "click" with an additional "ready"?

Thanks a lot!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').click(function() {
        $('input:not(:checked)').parents('div.options_selection.radio label').removeClass("activearticel");
        $('input:checked').parents('div.options_selection.radio label').addClass("activearticel");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is something you’ll need to accomplish with a session cookie or query string.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options

1. [Javascript cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
2. [Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)